# MySQL Group By Product Id BUT NOT Product that has a Serial Number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can someone help me how to make an efficient mysql query for this?

I need to make a query to get the sum quantity of all ordered items.

combined with.

I need to make a query to get the sum quantity of all received items.

Please note that **some products have serial numbers when received and some don't** in my 'received_po_details' table. That's where I'm having problem with since the sum of received gets doubled because of the serial numbers.

Table: received_po_details

```
i_rpoh_id   i_p_id  i_quantity_received s_product_serial
1           1       100 
1           2       100 
1           3       50  
1           4       25  
1           7       100 
1           8       50  
1           6       1                   XYZ1
1           6       1                   XYZ2
1           5       1                   ABC1
1           5       1                   ABC2
```

Right now I have these 2 separate sql that I need to combine.
**I don't want to use Union statement for this if possible**...

-- to get the Total Quantity Ordered

```
SELECT
    products.i_id AS 'ID',
    products.s_name AS 'Name',
    COALESCE(SUM(purchase_order_details.i_quantity_ordered),0) AS 'Total Quantity Ordered'
FROM
    products
LEFT JOIN
    purchase_order_details
    ON
    products.i_id = purchase_order_details.i_p_id
GROUP BY
    products.i_id   

-- to get the Total Quantity Received
SELECT
    products.i_id AS 'ID',
    products.s_name AS 'Name',
    COALESCE(SUM(received_po_details.i_quantity_received),0) AS 'Total Quantity Received'
FROM
    products
LEFT JOIN
    received_po_details
    ON
    products.i_id = received_po_details.i_p_id
GROUP BY
    products.i_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine these queries by creating a derived table or each type of sum (in the query below they're named `t1` and `t2`) and left joining the derived tables to the main product table.

```
SELECT
    p.i_id AS 'ID',
    p.s_name AS 'Name',
    COALESCE(t1.total,0) 'Total Quantity Ordered',
    COALESCE(t2.total,0) 'Total Quantity Received'
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        pod.i_p_id,
        SUM(pod.i_quantity_ordered) total
    FROM purchase_order_details pod
    GROUP BY pod.i_p_id
) t1 ON t1.i_p_id = p.i_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        rpd.i_p_id,
        SUM(rpd.i_quantity_received) total
    FROM received_po_details rpd
    GROUP BY rpd.i_p_id
) t2 ON p.i_id = t2.i_p_id
```

Comment: hi FuzzyTree,

what you did worked but I have some questions coz I'm a newb at this.. :)
- is this sql running 3 queries at the same time? 
- would that hurt the speed of the query and also the bandwidth side?
- would this query be the choice if we are like showing hundreds of data each paging?
- I don't understand what kind of sql statement you did with the left join and () with t1 and t2, what kind of sql statement is this so I can research and study more about it.

thanks

Comment: @anonymousmetoyou even though there are 3 `SELECT` clauses, they're all part of 1 query. `t1` and `t2` are called `derived tables`. for example, `t1` is a `derived table` consisting of 2 columns, the product id and the total quantity ordered. i believe this is the fastest possible query for the data you're looking for and it works well with paging (just add `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses at the end to select a specific page)